# Google Analytics: All users are 'unassigned' even though I have specified userId

Tags: google-analytics

I am using Universal Analytics Web Tracking (analytics.js), and am creating the tracker like so:

```
ga('create', MY_GOOGLE_TRACKING_ID, 'auto', { userId: 'myUserId');
```

When I examine the network traffic to google, all of the sends include the query parameter: uid:myUserId

I have enabled user Id tracking on my google 'property', and I have created a userId report and a non-userId report.

Google's documentation states:

> All reports in a User ID view display data from sessions in which a
>   User ID is assigned and related data are sent to Google Analytics. Use
>   a different view to see data from sessions in which a User ID is not
>   sent to Google Analytics.

When I look at the user Id view, I see 'realtime' data, including content and events, but if I look in the other sections, Audience/Behavior/etc, none of them have any content.

If I look at the non-user Id view, the 'realtime' data looks the same as the user Id view, which is fine, and the Audience/Behavior/etc all do include content.

When I look at the Audience -> Behavior -> User Id Coverage report, it says that 100% of the users are unassigned.

Any ideas how to get it to work like the docs *say* it works?

Comment: I'm running into the same problem, did you find a solution?

Comment: I honestly don't remember what I did to solve it.  I'll look around and see if I can figure it out.

Comment: no worries, I eventually found out that there was a problem with the Android SDK I was using. Thanks a lot :)